# Vertically Align Progressbar in Table

Tags: tables, xetex, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically center a progressbar inside of a table.  Below is a MWE,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{progressbar}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\vfill
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[!h]
\caption{Timeline for blah blah blah.}
\begin{tabular}{c l p{400pt} l}
    \toprule
    & Target & & \\
    & completion & & Percent \\
    Task & date & Milestone & complete \\
    \midrule
    0.0 & Whenever & \blindtext & \progressbar[width=100pt, heighta=12pt, roundnessr=0.25, ticksheight=0]{0} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\vfill
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `m{}` from `array` and `makecell`, but neither seemed to work.

Comment: Althought this needs manual adjustment, you could try using `multirow`.

Comment: @leandriis I'm not sure ``multirow`` will work, because there isn't explicitly multiple rows.  I just allowed the text to wrap in one of the columns in a single row.  Not sure I described that well, but does that make sense?

Comment: An `m` column seems to work fine here, how does that fail for you?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added an ``m`` column, but the progress bar stays at the top of the cell.  I want it in the middle of the cell.  I'm using ``This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex)``.

Comment: You need to make the `p` column into an `m` column.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You should turn this into an answer (it's quite unintuitive that it works).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That worked!  I made the 4th column (column with the progressbar) the ``m`` column, but apparently the ``p`` column needs to be the ``m`` column.  I'm not sure I follow why this works, but it does.  I agree with @Alan-Munn, post your reply again as an answer @TorbjørnT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the `p` column you have now into an `m` column, the `\progressbar` will be vertically centered with respect to the block of text:

[image: m-column]

As you can see, this applies to the first two columns as well.

Why does this work? Think of the table row as a line of text. The content of a `p` column is like a `\parbox[t]{<width>}{<text>}`, while that of an `m` column is like `\parbox[c]{<width>}{<text>}`  (as I understand it). The optional argument to a `\parbox` (`[t]`/`[c]`/`[b]`) indicates how it is placed on the baseline of the surrounding text. With `[t]`, the first line of the `parbox` is placed on the baseline, with `[c]` the (approximate) vertical center of the `parbox` is placed on the baseline. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo \parbox[t]{1cm}{bar baz box} lorem \parbox[c]{1cm}{bar baz box} ipsum.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same thing happens in a `tabular`, with a `p` column the "anchor point" is the first line of the cell, with `m` it's the center.

Another possibility would be to keep the `p` column and use `\raisebox{-60pt}{\progressbar[width=100pt, heighta=12pt, roundnessr=0.25, ticksheight=0]{0}}` (the `60pt` has to modified depending on the height of the  cell with the long text). This moves the `\progressbar` below the current baseline. The difference with using an `m` column is that the text in the first two columns are still aligned with the first line in the `Milestone` column, only the `\progressbar` moves.

[image: raisebox]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{progressbar}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\vfill
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Timeline for blah blah blah.}
\begin{tabular}{c l p{400pt} l}
    \toprule
    & Target & & \\
    & completion & & Percent \\
    Task & date & Milestone & complete \\
    \midrule
    0.0 & Whenever & \blindtext & \raisebox{-60pt}{\progressbar[width=100pt, heighta=12pt, roundnessr=0.25, ticksheight=0]{0}} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Timeline for blah blah blah.}
\begin{tabular}{c l m{400pt} l}
    \toprule
    & Target & & \\
    & completion & & Percent \\
    Task & date & Milestone & complete \\
    \midrule
    0.0 & Whenever & \blindtext & \progressbar[width=100pt, heighta=12pt, roundnessr=0.25, ticksheight=0]{0} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution and explanation!